# Issue with collapsing menu using wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wp-nav-walker

I'm developing my own wordpress theme for the first time, using bootstrap, and I've run into an issue when using the wp-bootstrap-navwalker.

I've created two menus, one that is visible in sm, md and lg, and one that is visible in xs. In xs it is supposed to be collapsed, and open on pressing the button, however after I added the wp-bootstrap-navwalker to my html, it is no longer working.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="description" content="Storhamar kunstløp har i dag nærmere 100 medlemmer og løpere på skøyteskole-, aspirant- og konkurransenivå. Her er man velkommen uansett ambisjonsnivå!">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Storhamar, SIL, kunstløp, figure skating, Hamar, skøyter, idrettslag, kunstløpklubb, skøyteklubb">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>

    <!--Fonts-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--Icons-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <header class="container-fluid hidden-xs">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
    </header>

<!--  Navbar   ================================================== -->
    <nav id="main-nav" class="navbar hidden-xs" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="280">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="main-nav-list">
             <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary-lg',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary-lg',
                'depth'             => 1,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'container-fluid',
                'container_id'      => 'main-nav-list',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav main-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
            ?>
        </div>
    </nav>

<!-- Mobile Navbar  ================================================== -->

    <nav id="mobile-nav" class="navbar mobile-nav navbar-default navbar-static-top visible-xs">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->  

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                 <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary-xs',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary-xs',
                'depth'             => 1,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
            ?>


            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->    
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <a href="index.html"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="img-responsive visible-xs center-block"></a>

<main class="container">
```

Here is my functions.php:

```
<?php 

    if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
        $content_width = 660;
    }

    function SILkunstlop_setup() {

        load_theme_textdomain('SILkunstlopLang', get_template_directory() . '/languages');

        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        // Register Custom Navigation Walker
        require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

        register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary-lg' => __( 'Hovedmeny stor', 'SILkunstlop-wp' ),
        ) );

        register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary-xs' => __( 'Hovedmeny liten', 'SILkunstlop-wp' ),
        ) );

        register_nav_menus( array(
        'sidebar-menu' => __( 'Sidemeny', 'SILkunstlop-wp' ),
        ) );

        register_nav_menus( array(
        'sidebar-menu2' => __( 'Sidemeny skøyteskole', 'SILkunstlop-wp' ),
        ) );


    }

    add_action('after_setup_theme', 'SILkunstlop_setup');

    //Load the theme CSS
    function theme_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    }

    //Load the theme JS
    function theme_js() {
        //Adds JQuery from Google's CDN. Code pulled from www.http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/
        if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
        function my_jquery_enqueue() {
            wp_deregister_script('jquery');
            wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", false, null);
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
            }
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

        if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );


    function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '...';
}

add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'aktuelt',
        'id'            => 'aktuelt',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="col-sm-8 hashtag">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

        register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'footer',
        'id'            => 'footer',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );

    function searchResult() {
        printf( __('Søkeresultat for: %s', 'SILkunstlopLang'), get_search_query());
    }

$args = array(
//  'width'         => 980,
    'height'        => 180,
    'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.svg',
    'uploads' => true,
);

add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );

$args = array(
    'default-color' => 'A9C5DD',
    'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/background.jpg',
    'default-attachment' => 'fixed',
    'default-repeat' => 'none',
    'default-position-x' => 'center',
    'default-position-y' => 'center',
    'uploads' => true,
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args );

?>
```

Does anyone have a clue to where my issue is originating?

Thanks a lot for any clues given, and let me know if I should include some more information!

Best,
Elena

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found the problem myself in the end, after studying the html once again with inspect element.

I didn't realise that the div around my nav is actually superfluous and just duplicated the container added by the menu. So after I removed the surrounding div with class of "collapse navbar-collapse" the menu collapsing menu worked again (opens on clicking the button).